# writing html bean within JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, struts, javabeans

hey Guys,
I am trying to write dynamic html bean using java script
but I keep geting the "function is not found" JS error when I press the button ..
here is a sample code

```
<html>
<html:form action="loginAction.do" >
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function test(){
            document.getElementById('dd').innerHTML =
                              "<html:text property='pid'/>";
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
            <table align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                    <input type="button" value="addprod" onclick="test()"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <div id="dd"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </html:form>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know about the

```
<html:form action="loginAction.do" >
```

where it should be located 
I tried to locate it within the `<body>`
but I got a big exception due to  writing `<html:text property='pid'/>` in JavaScript outside the `<html:form>` 
...
need your help,
Regards,

Comment: Err... what is that `<html:form action="loginAction.do" >` supposed to do outside the body? And why is the closing tag inside it?

Comment: yes .. it's wrong I know !!!
am telling you , it's supposed to be within the <body> tag
but by doing this , I get a huge exception due to writing 
"<html:text property='pid'/>";
in JavaScript outside the <html:form>
That's the problem ...

Comment: Are there any errors in your JavaScript console?  Is it possible that `<html:text property='pid'/>` contains double quotes or newline characters thus causing the script block to fail to parse?

Comment: I don't think so Mike , it's just a one line code , and I rewrited it many times...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think struts is trying to parse the `<html:text />` as a tag in your script, rather that just a javascript string. Try moving the `<html:form action="loginAction.do" >` into the body AND the `<script>` within the `<html:form>` similar to this fiddle http://www.jsfiddle.net/pL4Aq/1/

However, it works in the fiddle because it is just straight HTML... I don't think what you are trying to do will work. `<html:text >` is a custom tag that gets processed on the server, does a bunch of stuff, and then generates HTML for you. You will never actually see `<html:text>` if you view the source from your browser, even though it is in your jsp.

You might want to try changing the `<html:text >` to a straight `<input type="text">` tag (in which case, you could just move the `<html:form>` into the body and leave the script where it is).

Comment: thanks Mike ,I've looked for this problem, and I've found out exactly what you have just said , regards

Answer (score 1):

I am completely agreed with what Mike is saying.
Writing `<html:text>` inside javascript is useless since javascript is executing on client side while struts is required to translate this tag to html tag.
Better to write `<input type="text">` inside javascript and keeps its name as "prop" if you want struts to fill the value of that text inside the form bean property "prop". Keep the `<html:form` in body tag. This will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

It should work in a `<body>` tag.

Comment: I got exception for writing <html:text> outside <html:form>